# Complicated Validations with Many Fields in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord

I have a model (ProjectedSquad) that belongs to another model (SoldierBio) with many different foreign keys. I want to validate that certain fields have a uid value that only appears once in the row, while other fields do not need to have a unique value.

Is there an efficient or Rails way to run these kind of complex validations?

As of right now, the custom validations contain nested each blocks and check if each field has a value contained in other fields. It's slow and messy but it does work. Is there a better way?

The relationship between the two objects, though odd, has to be structured this way (ProjectedSquad belongs to SoldierBio as lt, lt2, col, gen etc...).

```
class ProjectedSquad < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :soldier_bio, foreign_key: :lt_uid
  belongs_to :soldier_bio, foreign_key: :lt2_uid
  belongs_to :soldier_bio, foreign_key: :col_uid
  belongs_to :soldier_bio, foreign_key: :maj_uid
  belongs_to :soldier_bio, foreign_key: :gen_uid
  belongs_to :soldier_bio, foreign_key: :pfc_uid
  belongs_to :soldier_bio, foreign_key: :cpl_uid
  belongs_to :soldier_bio, foreign_key: :medic_uid
  belongs_to :soldier_bio, foreign_key: :radio_uid
  belongs_to :soldier_bio, foreign_key: :tech_uid
  belongs_to :soldier_bio, foreign_key: :sonar_uid

  RANKS = [:lt_uid, :lt2_uid, :col_uid, :maj_uid, :gen_uid, :pfc_uid, :cpl_uid]

  SPECIALS = [:radio_uid, :tech_uid, :sonar_uid, :medic_uid]

  validate :unique_rank
  validate :multiple_specials
  validate :multiple_specials_is_officer


  private

  def unique_rank
    ## can only have one rank

    # RANKS.each do |rank_uid|
      # if array of rank uid values includes self.rank
      # self.errors.add(rank_uid, "can't have multiple ranks")
    # end
  end

 def specials
  ## can have same uid value both for a rank and a special
  ## cannot have same uid in multiple specials
 end

 def multiple_specials_is_officer
  ## same uid for 2 specials
  ## uid cannot appear in pfc_uid or cpl_uid, but can in one other rank    field
 end 


end
```

Comment: Is it possible that the underlying data model is not mapping the reality? To me it looks like a *Rank* model, a *Special* (maybe *Capability*?) model and a *SoldierBio* model. And SoldierBio belongs_to a Rank and also belongs_to Special. Then validating is simple. You also would not need those Constants and implementing other features probably would be easier as well.

Comment: I do need it structured this way unfortunately. Firstly, the uid's aren't the only keys. We have id's for two separate data sources on soldier_bio. This isn't the actual code, I just tried to come up with a close example. Given that I can't change the architecture, what do you think?